# RMI cache replication in EHCache 3.1

Tags: rmi, ehcache

I'm currently using RMI cache replication with EHCache version 2.x and planning to upgrade to 3.1. Is RMI cache replication supported in EHCache 3.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no ready to use RMI replication module in Ehcache 3.x and no plan on providing one.

While Ehcache 3.x can be configured to have cache event listeners with guaranteed ordering, replication remains a scheme inferior to distributed caches as it does not provide any solution for concurrent updates and only supports *last write wins* which is insufficient for most use cases.

As such the recommendation is to use Ehcache 3.x clustering.